# When creating a tensor with an array of timestamps, the numbers are incorrect

Tags: tensorflow.js

Looking for some kind of solution to this issue:

trying to create a tensor from an array of timestamps

```
[
  1612892067115,
],
```

but here is what happens

```
tf.tensor([1612892067115]).arraySync()
> [ 1612892078080 ]
```

as you can see, the result is incorrect.
Somebody pointed out, I may need to use the datatype int64, but this doesn't seem to exist in tfjs

I have also tried to divide my timestamp to a small float, but I get a similar result

```
tf.tensor([1.612892067115, 1.612892068341]).arraySync()
[ 1.6128920316696167, 1.6128920316696167 ]
```

If you know a way to work around using timestamps in a tensor, please help :)

:edit:

As an attempted workaround, I tried to remove my year, month, and date from my timestamp

Here are my subsequent input values:

```
[
  56969701,
  56969685,
  56969669,
  56969646,
  56969607,
  56969602
]
```

and their outputs:

```
[
  56969700,
  56969684,
  56969668,
  56969648,
  56969608,
  56969600
]
```

as you can see, they are still incorrect, and should be well within the acceptable range

Answer (score 0):

Currently only int32 is supported with tensorflow.js, your data has gone out of the range supported by int32.

Until int64 is supported, this can be solved by using a relative timestamp. Currently a timestamp in js uses the number of ms that elapsed since 1 January 1970. A relative timestamp can be used by using another origin and compute the difference of ms that has elapsed since that date. That way, we will have a lower number that can be represented using int32. The best origin to take will be the starting date of the records

```
const a = Date.now() // computing a tensor out of it will give an accurate result since the number is out of range

const origin = new Date("02/01/2021").now()

const relative = a - origin
const tensor = tf.tensor(relative, undefined, 'int32')
// get back the data
const data = tensor.dataSync()[0]
// get the initial date
const initial date = new Date(data + origin)
```

In other scenarios, if using the ms is not of interest, using the number of s that has elapsed since the start would be better. It is called the [unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

Comment: can you suggest some sort of workaround for things like timestamps?

Comment: by the way, did you notice the issue with the float numbers in the second example?

Comment: You are exceeding the number of precision a float32 can hold

Comment: I am afraid, you can't use tensorflow.js with such big numbers as for now

Comment: updated my question with a smaller number that still gives issues, you can run this in your console and see the same result. The last test case should be within the range, no?

Comment: You need to add the dtype, `int32` otherwise it will default to `float32` and you are still exceeding the range

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228535/discussion-between-edkeveked-and-eli7vh).

Answer (score 0):

found a solution that worked for me:

Since I only require a subset of the timestamp (just the date / hour / minute / second / ms) for my purposes, I simply truncate out the year / month:

```
export const subts = (ts: number) => {
  // a sub timestamp which can be used over the period of a month
  const yearMonth = +new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth())
  return ts - yearMonth
}
```

then I can use this with:

```
subTimestamps = timestamps.map(ts => subts(ts))
const x_vals = tf.tensor(subTimestamps, [subTimestamps.length], 'int32')
```

now all my results work as expected.